# Build query using QueryBuilders in rest client

Tags: elasticsearch

By using rest client

```
Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String qqq = g.toJson(query.toString());
        paramMap.put("q", "make:chevrolet");
        paramMap.put("pretty", "true");
        try {

            Response response = restClient.performRequest("GET", "vehicles/_search", paramMap);
            return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Here instead of using map object ,how to build query using the QueryBuilders